# How to convert XSL to PDF using Spire PDFConverter in .NET?

Tags: .net, file-conversion

I typed this code:

```
Workbook book = new Workbook();
book.LoadFromFile("C:\\Tmp_Export20160322_145936.xlsx");
book.SaveToFile("C:\\MyPDF.pdf");
```

But it throws the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Requested value 'border' was not found.
```

It says the file is not there but it is. By the way I don't have Microsoft Excell installed on my computer. I don't know if that is the problem. Why it says requested value border wasn't found , I've never tried to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and didn't reproduce the issue you described. But there is indeed a small error in your code that you forgot to input another parameter in the method *SaveToFile()*, which may causes failure when converting.

```
Workbook book = new Workbook();
book.LoadFromFile("C:\\sample.xlsx");
book.SaveToFile("C:\\MyPDF.pdf",FileFormat.PDF);
```

If this doesn't help solve the problem, you can turn to their [forum](http://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/spire-xls-f4.html) for professional support.